# Details view as default in picture library

Tags: 2010, library, picture-library, image-display

I'm using SharePoint 2010 and I would like to automatically display a pictures library with the "details view". Obviously not only for my account, but that view should be set as default for all users.

I've searched all options but I didn't find nothing, so did I search wrong or should I write JavaScript (and append it to the page) to automatically switch the view?

Answer (score 2):

Well I can understand your query my friend, its very simple to do this, create a new view and modify the Style Category to "Basic Table" and set this view as default view. You will get what you are looking for .Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default view for a picture library the same way you would for any other library or list:

1) While viewing the list, select Settings menu and then Picture Library Settings.

2) Scroll to the bottom where the Views are listed.

3) Select the desired view.

4) Mark the box that says "Make this the default view"

5) Select OK.

Comment: I tried the same thing in SHarepoint 2010 for a PowerPIvot Gallery - No matter what I do, it switches back to Gallery view when I go to another page and come back to this. The setting still say "All documents is the default view" ANy pointers?